# How to convert netstat -in output on Sunos

Tags: netstat, sunos

On Sunos netstat -in gives me below output.

```
Name  Mtu  Net/Dest      Address        Ipkts  Ierrs Opkts  Oerrs Collis Queue 
lo0   832 127.0.0.0     127.0.0.1      20026 0     20026 0     0      0     
nxge0 100 192.168.0.0  192.168.0.31 40957 0     465768 0     0      0
```

Is it possible to change the input/output values to volume i.e. in KB, etc. OR Please advise if there is any other way to find how much data (in Kb or Mb) transmitted from my NIC.

Comment: This should be taken over to serverfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get these values on Solaris by using kstat.

eg:

```
kstat -c net -n nxge0 | grep bytes64
```

PS: There's nothing in /proc which isn't process related, unlike Linux.

Answer (score -1):

You can't get that info from netstat, but there's probably something in the /proc filesystem that will give the statistics.